# how to turn off mousewheel in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mousewheel

I want to disable the mouse wheel in jQuery and I did it but I'm getting this error

> jquery.min.js:2 [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312

This is the code in JS file:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(window).bind("mousewheel", function() {
    return false;
  });
})
```

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm guessing it doesn't as the code in that dupe is the same as the OP is using (and outdated)

Comment: Can you clarify what the goal is? Is the user not supposed to scroll the page at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is because you cannot call `preventDefault()` on passive events, such as `mousewheel` is - among others.

To fix the issue you can set `passive: false` when you bind the event handler:

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', e => e.preventDefault(), {
  passive: false
});
```

```css
/* just to make the scrollbar appear in this demo */
body { height: 5000px; }
```

*However*, I would strongly suggest you **do not do this**. Preventing users from navigating your site using the very popular mouse scroll wheel will be incredibly annoying for you users - and possibly make them believe your site is malfunctioning.

Comment: JQuery hasn't yet implemented the options argument?

Comment: @Teemu not that I could see, no.

Comment: @Teemu do you can say me how can I turn on scrolling

Comment: @Agata Maybe Rory edits their answer to include that too ..?

Comment: @Agata if you want to turn on scrolling, don't use this event handler :) if you mean you want to toggle this block on scrolling at runtime, remove the event handler: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  window.removeEventListener('wheel', e => e.preventDefault, {
            passive: false
        }); it doesnt work

Comment: @Agata here's a demo of how you can toggle the scroll block: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/163Ldg02/

Comment: No problem, glad to help.